# iPhone: For integrating Code versioning thru SVN, is it necessary to upload files on a Server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, svn, xcode4

Please forgive my ignorance, but I am noob.

I have 4 Macs in my Office. I want to integrate SVN repository with XCode so that all of us can work on same project at the same time.

Is it necessary to setup SVN repository on a remote server? Can it be installed on any of these 4 Macs?

Please let me know.

Comment: Even if you place the repo on any of the Macs, that Mac would essentially be the server.

Comment: Ok. But in that case how do we get the path of that repository. In case of webserver, we have http://www.servername/repo/. What would be the path in case if we setup a mac as server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not *necessary*, but it definitely helps to avoid some nagging problems that can come up when you install the SVN server on a developer machine. For example:

1. Developer machine needs to be rebooted because he installed software, or ran into memory issues, or applied a patch etc etc.
2. Developer forgets that he is hosting the server and shuts down for the night. Meanwhile you were wanting to burn the midnite oil but don't have the latest revs.
3. Developer kicks power cord while you were in the middle of a commit.
4. Developer browses to a 'work related' site and now he's getting Russian bride pop-ups every few seconds. Frack, time for a reformat and darn if you don't gotta move the SVN server too.
5. ... I'm sure you get the drift

SVN is pretty forgiving, and to be honest you could probably scrape by with installing it on a dev machine, but using a dedicated server is ***so*** much better.

Now, if you really want an SCM solution that Just Works, take a look at Git. XCode actually supports it natively and it's designed to work server-lessly. IMO it's a much better tool than SVN and worth dedicating some time to learn.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer. Regarding Git, we are having really hard time when working on same project. If someone is working on the project and other person from his machine tries to run the project, Xcode ALWAYS crashes. So, we have no option but to work one person at a time which is really painful. Is there a better way to use Git?

Comment: @meetpd - Sorry for the late response. There are a number of clients for Git that make it much easier to use, Tower being one of them: http://www.git-tower.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use SVN locally with a repository that is a file on your local machine. However that's not what you want.  You want to share files between computers, in which case you'll need one of the computers to be a server.

Here is a good guide for setting up svn on the mac: [Subversion Server Guide Mac](http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-mac-os.html)

The quickest option is to use a service like Beanstalk ([http://beanstalkapp.com](http://beanstalkapp.com/)) to host the repository.  Then you wont' have to mess with server setup and admin.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. Any idea what would be the path in case if we setup a mac as server?